# Getting Error once create a multimedia component through Core Service using wshttp end point

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am getting the below error message once create  a multimedia component through Core Service using wshttp end point.

```
The message could not be processed because the action 'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011/IStreamUpload/UploadBinaryContent' is invalid or unrecognized.

string tempLocation = "";
            using (var streamClient = GetStreamConnection(coreService))
            {
                FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                //Getting Error message in below line 
                tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent(fileInfo.Name.ToLower(), objfilestream);
            }

            BinaryContentData bcdData = new BinaryContentData
            {
                UploadFromFile = tempLocation,
                MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData { IdRef = mmType },
                Filename = fileInfo.Name,
                IsExternal = false
            };
```

/*****************************************************************************************/

```
 public static StreamUploadClient GetStreamConnection(CoreServiceFrameworkWsHttpContext coreService)
        {

            MaxxedWsHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new MaxxedWsHttpBinding();

            EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(coreService.EndpointUri); //EndpointUri = http://........../webservices/CoreService2011.svc/wsHttp

            StreamUploadClient client = new StreamUploadClient(wsHttpBinding, remoteAddress);
            try
            {
                client.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return client;
        }
```

Comment: It seems you get it wrong in constructor of StreamUploadClient. Could you post your configs?

Comment: @user978511 i am using core service without config file and creating a SessionAwareCoreServiceClient using wshttp

Comment: what is your remoteAddress?

Comment: @user978511 - I have updated in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the Core Service's HTTP stream upload endpoints use a BasicHttpBinding. See the example binding configuration in Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config (or in server-side configuration: the web.config of the webservices webapp).

The name `MaxxedWsHttpBinding` hints at a WsHttpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding (it is rather confusing that the variable is named `basicHttpBinding`, though).
In general, I would recommend to just use these provided binding configurations instead of trying to configure/hard-code everything programmatically.

Comment: yes, I am using MaxxedWsHttpBinding, the name has create some confusion, I have update that in my question, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: With your update, your code is more consistent, but that doesn't fix the issue. The issue is that you have to use a BasicHttpBinding (configured for streaming) instead of a WsHttpBinding. You can only use an WsHttpBinding for the Core Service's main endpoint/contract (ISessionAwareCoreService)

Comment: I just noticed the endpoint URL you are using ends with /wsHttp.  That is the URL of the "main" endpoint.  You should use a URL ending with /streamUpload instead (next to using an approprately configured BasicHttpBinding)

Comment: Thanks, I got my mistake, yes, you are correct, I miss /streamUpload url for end point to upload the Image.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your code, it seems you are trying to create `StreamUploadClient` passing `MaxxedWsHttpBinding` and `EndpointAddress`.

I am assuming you are getting the correct value in `coreService.EndpointUri` while creating the endpoint address object.

About the issue, I guess it could be related to the security context of the Binding. Though, you did not explain about `MaxxedWsHttpBinding`. but I guess you need to adjust the security settings for the binding.

To begin with disabling it, you can try somthing like

```
MaxxedWsHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new MaxxedWsHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
```

If it resolves the issue, then for sure it's a security related issue. if you don't want to disable the security context, adjust it according to your need. 
The below link could be useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have set the Security Message EstablishSecurityContext as flase, but its throwing the "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.", I have updated endpoint uri information in my question.

Comment: Hi Priyank,
This is a separate issue, this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc60cd6d-1df9-47ff-90a8-dd8d5de1f080/the-communication-object-cannot-be-used-because-it-is-in-the-faulted-state?forum=wcf) could be useful for that.                          Here, I suggest you to restart the Core Service (Windows TCM Host Service). In your code I can see only
`client.Open()`. Plz  use `client.close()` in conjunction with it, once you are done with the core service operation. Hope this helps.